# Angular2 - Group and selectively add module declarations

Tags: angular, declaration, angular-cli

We're using angular2 and the angular-cli, and our app is becoming fairly large and has a large number of `declarations:` in the `app.module.ts` file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GameComponent1,
    GameComponent2,
    GameComponent3,
    StatsComponent1,
    StatsComponent2,
    StatsComponent3,
    AboutPageComponent1,
    AboutPageComponent2,
    AboutPageComponent3,
    AboutPageComponent4,
  ],...
```

First of all, is there a way to group related component declarations like the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GameComponentsGroup,
    StatsComponentsGroup,
    AboutPageComponentsGroup,
  ],...
```

Then could it be possible to selectively switch on and off components from being included in the build, for different environments.

```
if(environment.envName == "developmentWithStats")
  appmodule add StatsComponentsGroup
```

The goal is to allow different features to be included in different builds.

I know I'm missing some key knowledge here, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, is there a way to group related component declarations like the following:

You could group them into a different module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ Game1Component, Game2Component ],
  exports: [ Game1Component, Game2Component ]
})
class GameModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ GameModule ]
})
class ModuleThatUsesGameModule {}
```

> Then could it be possible to selectively switch on and off components from being included in the build, for different environments.

You could do something like

```
const declarations = [
  CoreComponent
];

if(environment.envName == "developmentWithStats") {
  declarations.push(SomeComponent);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: declarations
})
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed! Appreciate your time to answer this